# Multiple Containments with connectwith

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I been searching all morning for an answer but have not been able to find any answer.
What I am looking to do is have multiple div containers, with 2 sortables within that div.

Looks something like...

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>first item</li>
        <li>second item</li>
        <li>third item</li>
        <li>fourth item</li>
        <li>fifth item</li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li>6th</li>
        <li>7th</li>
        <li>8th</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>first item</li>
        <li>second item</li>
        <li>third item</li>
        <li>fourth item</li>
        <li>fifth item</li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li>6th</li>
        <li>7th</li>
        <li>8th</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The second ul inside the div will be empty. They will drag their choices from the first ul to it. But they cannot drag options from different containers. The amount of div containers will be dynamic as well. I was wondering if this can be done within 1 script or am I going to have to do multiple scripts...

Thank in advance for the help

Comment: Here is something close to what I want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/85ncc/48/

Only issue is that the second box doesnt work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not come up with how to build just one script statement. So what I did was built a php loop based on how many options they needed to print out the scripts for each option. Probably not the best way of doing it but I could not figure out how to make 1 single script.

Here is my code I used.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= RANDOM AMOUNT; $x++){
        echo '$(function() {      
            $( ".sortable'.$x.'" ).sortable({
               containment: "#c'.$x.'",
               connectWith: ".sortable'.$x.'",update:function(e,ui){
                    if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
                    var order = $("#myList'.$x.'").sortable("serialize");

                    }
               }
            })
        });';

    }
```

Hopefully this may help someone or someone based on this can come up with a better solution.